# Excluding files from top level directory when extracting tar archives

Tags: linux, extract, glob, tar

I have a .tar.gz archive on my Linux machine that I want to extract.
When I do `tar -tf archive.tar.gz`, I get the following output:

```
test1
a/ 
a/test1
```

What I'm trying to do is exclude the file `test1` in the top-level-directory of the archive. However, I haven't found a working solution...

What I've tried to do is `tar -xvf archive.tar.gz --exclude=test1`. However, this excludes all occurences of files with that name, so it also excludes `a/test1` which I do not want to exclude.
Using `tar -xvf archive.tar.gz --exclude=./test1` also doesn't work (this excludes neither files). I suppose this is because there doesn't seem to be a 'top level directory'. However, I do not have control over the structure of the archive. And since the `--exclude` options seems to use glob patterns, I also can't use an expression like `--exclude=^test1`.
I'm not really sure what to do now as I can't find a way to exclude only the file I want to exclude.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about _using_ `tar`, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/313677) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know if this is the best way to do it but here it is anyway.*

1. Exclude a file pattern (test1) and list all directories & files

```bash
tar -tf archive.tar.gz --exclude test1
```

2. Use this list as input for extracting

```bash
tar -xf archive.tar.gz $(tar -tf archive.tar.gz --exclude test1)

# or

tar -tf archive.tar.gz --exclude test1 | xargs tar -xf archive.tar.gz
```

For the following directory heirarchy in my own archive

```
test1
b/b_2/
c/
b/b_1.txt
c/test1
a/test1
a/
b/b_1/
b/
```

I was able to use this approach to exclude just `test1` from the toplevel.

```
b/b_2/
c/
b/b_1.txt
c/test1
a/test1
a/
b/b_1/
b/
```